# how do I store indiscriminate objects in a rails session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I want to store non-marshallable objects in a rails session.  In particular a https://github.com/toland/patron/blob/master/lib/patron/session.rb object, but I want a solution that would work for any ruby object.

I don't care about object size, security, forward-compatibility, speed.  I don't care about using multiple servers and memory space accessibility, there will always be one server.  I don't want to write a serializer for every object that may end up in the session.

Would a cache scheme be a better choice?  How would I implement one for a session if so?  These are not ActiveRecord objects so do not tell me to store the id and look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Quite and simple, you can't store ANY object in a session, only objects that can be easily marshalled and unmarshalled. A very common example is IO/File objects, there is no way to marshall such objects without using specialized serializers/deserializers.

It's probably simpler if you explain **what** you want instead of defining **how** you want it in your question.

Comment: there's a comment at the bottom of my question about if I could be served better with a cache solution.

Comment: Caches will also require serialization :)

Comment: all caches will require serialization?

Comment: The only one that wouldn't is a memory-only cache but this kind of cache isn;t really useful for rails apps since each app runs in it's own process and would not share memory.

Comment: as I said in my question, sharing memory is not a problem.  There will only be one server instance. I went with this: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-lru